# Object code generation for new RISCV instruction emitted by LLVM backend

Tags: llvm, riscv, object-files

From https://github.com/riscv/riscv-llvm,

> Using the llvm-riscv is fairly simple to build a full executable
>   however you need riscv64-unknown-*-gcc to do the assembling and
>   linking. An example of compiling hello world:

```
$ clang -target riscv64 -mriscv=RV64IAMFD -S hello.c -o hello.S
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o hello.riscv hello.S
```

My question is: if I change the LLVM backend and get it to emit a new instruction in the hello.S file, how will `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` know how to convert it into object code? Do I also need to make changes in `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` so that it knows the format of the new instruction?

Comment: yes you need apply changes in xxxInstrInfo.td file.

Answer (score 0):

`riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` calls `as`, i.e. usually GNU `as` from the binutils to assemble assembly code (i.e. `hello.S` in your snippet) into executable machine code. Thus you would have to modify the binutils if you want to assemble a new instruction.